# Two Dimensional Array farthest point search

Tags: c#, arrays, search

I am trying to retrieve the farthest point in a collection, by comparing the distances from each point in the `pointsToSearchFrom` List to each other point in the `pointCloudToSearchList`. You can see a sample scenario from the attached image. I am still not an expert in navigating these data structures, and this algorithm exceeds my current knowledge of traversing two dimensional arrays.

Here is the code that I have until know. Any help would be great.

```
public static void Test(List<Point3d> pointsToSearchFrom, List<Point3d> pointCloudToSearch)
{
    int rows = pointsToSearchFrom.Count;
    int columns = pointCloudToSearch.Count;
    double[,] arrayDistance = new double [rows, columns];

    for (int i = 0; i < pointsToSearchFrom.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < pointCloudToSearch.Count; j++)
        {
            arrayDistance[i, j] = (pointsToSearchFrom[i] - pointCloudToSearch[j]).magnitude;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: is this a homework? but hey, you almost there, i believe you could just iterate with two `for` just like how you calculate the distance between points and find the maximum or minimum. However, if you only concerned with the largest or smallest distance you can just dump the largest `i` and `j` point you found and the distance then update it if it is larger than previous one.

Comment: No its not a homework lol, its just a personal work that I am trying to do, but I am not a pro in coding. Yes, the smallest or largest distance is straight foreword, but I don't know how to retrieve the farthest point in the pointsToSearchFrom List based on the distance

Comment: So what you have here is two sets of points. You wish to form all possible pairs of points where the first is drawn from the first set and the second is drawn from the second. From that set of pairs, you wish to find the pair which maximizes the Euclidean distance between the points?

Comment: @EricLippert yes, that's correct. The next step that I would need to do I believe is sort all the distances stored on each row, and then optain the longest distances on each row, this will produce a 9X1  `Array`, that could then be converted to a `List`, so its in the same data structure as  `pointsToSearchFrom`. Then I could just find the index of the item with the greatest distance and use that to retrieve my farthest point from `pointsToSearchFrom`. But I cant seem to come up with a way to do Sort the data on each row.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a two-d array for this, but you do not have to.

What you need is the MaxBy method which can be found here:

https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs

We begin by constructing a sequence of pairs:

```
var pairs = from first in pointsToSearchFrom
            from second in pointCloudToSearch
            select new { first, second };
```

Note that in C# 7 you would use a tuple, not an anonymous type here.

Now we have a sequence of all possible pairs.  Use MaxBy to find the pair that maximizes the given quantity:

```
var maxPair = pairs.MaxBy(pair => (pair.first - pair.second).magnitude);
```

And now you're done:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{maxPair.first} --> {maxPair.second});
```

If you have a large collection of points -- like, thousands or millions -- then there are special techniques you have to use, because if there are thousands of points then there will be millions of pairs, and if there are millions of points there will be trillions of pairs. But if you just have a small handful, this technique works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't catch on at first that this was 3D. I used a class and list to store the 2 points and the distances between them. That way I could not only get the longest distance but the 2 points producing the distance.

```
    public class Distances
    {
        public double Distance { get; set; }
        public Point3D FromPoint { get; set; }
        public Point3D ToPoint { get; set; }

        public Distances(Point3D from, Point3D to)
        {
            FromPoint = from;
            ToPoint = to;
            Distance = (to - from).Length;
        }
    }
    private void OP2()
    {
        List<Point3D> searchFrom = new List<Point3D>()
        {
        new Point3D(20,30,50),
        new Point3D(10,50,10),
        new Point3D(30,40,20),
        new Point3D(60,30,10)
        };

        List<Point3D> searchCloud = new List<Point3D>()
        {
        new Point3D(60,70,80),
        new Point3D(110,30,30),
        new Point3D(80,110,55),
        new Point3D(90,20,90)
        };
        List<Distances> resultDistances = new List<Distances>();
        foreach (Point3D p1 in searchFrom)
        {
            foreach (Point3D p2 in searchCloud)
            {
                Distances d = new Distances(p1, p2);
                resultDistances.Add(d);
            }
        }
        //The following is just for testing purposes, skip to var longestDistance
        List<Distances> distancesInOrder = resultDistances.OrderByDescending(i => i.Distance).ToList<Distances>();
        foreach (Distances d in distancesInOrder)
        {
            Debug.Print($"From Point ({d.FromPoint.X}, {d.FromPoint.Y}, {d.FromPoint.Z}) To Point ({d.ToPoint.X}, {d.ToPoint.Y}, {d.ToPoint.Z}) Distance = {d.Distance}");
        }
        var longestDistance = resultDistances.OrderByDescending(i => i.Distance).FirstOrDefault();
        //this gives you the longest distance and the two points
        MessageBox.Show($"First Point ({longestDistance.FromPoint.X}, {longestDistance.FromPoint.Y}, {longestDistance.FromPoint.Z}) Cloud Point ({longestDistance.ToPoint.X}, {longestDistance.ToPoint.Y}, {longestDistance.FromPoint.Z}) Distance = {longestDistance.Distance}");
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I have used a similar method before and it works, but I am also very interested in being able to store data in Multidemensional Arrays. For instance a 9X8 Array, corresponding to 9 Rows which store  the number of points and 8 Columns corresponding to the number of distances. And then being able to iterate through each row and sort the distances, to further retrieve the shortest distance for example. This operation will then create a new Matrix of 9X1 dimensions. Do you know of any good resource to begin looking in to this?

Comment: The distancesInOrder contains the sorted list of the Distances class so you have the point to search from, the cloud point and the distance between stored in each item of the last in order of distance. You can easily select the lowest and hight index to get all the infor about the points and distances.